# How can I build a dynamic Data Validation on Google app scripts based on a specific row in another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Spreadsheet with two sheets, "menu" and "parts", I want to build a Data validation on "menu" that brings different values on a drop down menu, refering to the row of the sheet "parts".

`````
var line = parseInt(currentLine);

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
var menuSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Menu");
var partSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Parts");
var partCell = menuSheet.getRange('B1:B11');
var partLastRow = partSheet.getLastRow();

var line = 5 // here I defined the line to check if the code is functioning
var partRange = partSheet.getRange("A"+line+":"+line);
var partRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(partRange).build();
partCell.setDataValidation(partRule)
//console.log()
}````


In "parts" I have 10 values in each row, row 1 (1 to 10) row 2 (11 to 20) and there it goes.
I want to the first dropdown validation on "B1" to bring me options from 1 to 10 on "B2" from 11 to 20 and so on.
`````

Comment: Use openById,getValues() and bring them in as a string and use requireinList

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really good, but I'm not sure how this would workout, both sheets are on the same spreadsheet, so there is not direct problem with ID connection

Comment: I think the easiest way to solve this is figuring out the function call and passing the parameter to the formula